# Почему "а капелла" раздельно, а "а-ля" - через дефис?

Tags: орфография

Кто нам артикли придумывает?

В "а капелла" какая-нито логика присутствует?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вероятно, потому, что 'à la' - составной предлог из французского, части которого при переносе в русский объединены дефисом (ср. с русскими "из-под", "из-за"), а 'a' - просто предлог (в составе заимствованного итальянского термина). С существительным оба предлога пишутся раздельно, т.е. имеет место единообразие.

Comment: Есть ли прецеденты с заимствованным раздельно пишущимся предлогом. Ну, кроме означенного?

Comment: а ля гер ком а ля гер http://gallicismes.academic.ru/1307/%D0%B0_%D0%BB%D0%B0_%D0%B3%D0%B5%D1%80_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC_%D0%B0_%D0%BB%D0%B0_%D0%B3%D0%B5%D1%80 - здесь как раз выражение, где нет функции составного предлога, а просто "предлог + артикль".

Comment: Несправедливость какая!

Answer (score 6):

Эти выражения заимствованы из разных языков.

> A capella

В итальянском означает "*как церковный хор*", "*в манере церковного хора*".  Здесь церковный хор не имеет определённого артикля, потому что любой церковный хор пел без сопровождения.

> À la

во французском означает "*в манере (или в стиле)*" чего-то, которому предшествует определённый артикль, подчёркивая специфичность того, чему уподобляется продукт или явление.

По-видимому, в русском (как и во некоторых других языках) эта комбинация предлога с определённым артиклем стала играть роль предлога, но слиться окончательно в "аля" так ей и не удалось.

Comment: Что нам мешает унифицировать написание этих "а"? Акапеллу вообще хочется слитно нарисовать...

Comment: Например, то, что такое слитно написанное слово не встроить в русскую речь без склонения и предлогов, искажающих исходный смысл - оно вынужденно сохраняет отчётливые признаки цитаты. Лично я писал бы это словосочетание в тексте либо латиницей, либо в кавычках.